# Managing acronyms in bilingual document

Tags: babel, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I have a (big) document, mostly in english, with few chapters in french. I compile with pdfLaTeX. I use `glossaries-extra` (heavily) to define acronyms, and I would like to achieve the following:

1. print a single list of acronyms in the english part of the document.
   All usages of `\gls{}` should hyperlink to this list.
2. chapters in english: the acronyms are printed using the `long-short`
   abbreviation style
3. chapters in french have two cases: acronyms that are translated and those that are not
4. non-translated acronyms: still
   printed using the `long-short` style, but with the long form in
   *italic*. For this, I have a first solution
5. translated acronyms: the first use of `\gls{}` should print the long form in french,
   followed by the short form and the long form in english within
   parenthesis, e.g. **forme longue (LF, long form)** (not in **bold** of course. Plus, the short form
   is never translated). Subsequent use of `\gls{}` prints the
   short form as usual. This is were I am currently stuck.

Approaches I have tried include:

1. use `long-short-user` style with empty description in english, but it produces an ugly comma at the end of the short form
2. define two acronyms (one in french and the other in english) that link to the same one (in english) on the (only) list

I include below a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,oneside,french,english]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[automake,acronym,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries-extra}


% glossary definitions
\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[longshort]{long-short}

\newcommand{\enfr}[2]{\protect\IfLanguageName{french}{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\newenacro}[4][]{%
  \newabbreviation[#1,type=\acronymtype]{#2}{#3}{\enfr{#4}{\textit{#4}}}%
}

\newabbreviation[type=\acronymtype,category=longshort]{eu}{EU}{\enfr{European Union}{Union Européenne}}
\newenacro[category=longshort]{us}{US}{United States}

\title{My fantastic title}
\author{It's me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]

\chapter{English chapter}

English-only acronym: \gls{us} and \gls{us}.

\noindent
English-french acronym: \gls{eu} and \gls{eu}.

\glsresetall
\begin{otherlanguage}{french}\NoAutoSpacing

\chapter{Chapitre en français}

Acronyme en anglais uniquement~: \gls{us} et encore~: \gls{us}.

\noindent
Acronyme anglais-français~: \gls{eu} et encore~: \gls{eu}.

\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

The list of acronyms and how they appear in the english chapter are OK. The french part currently produces:
[image: result in french chapter]

but instead of **Union Européenne (EU)** I would like to see **Union Européenne (EU, European Union)**. I could use categories to distinguish the two cases.

Bonus question: proper management of the plural form, since in french must be almost always customized on a per-acronym base.

Thank you very much.